# My android application changes default language to english

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created three strings

> values-en
>
> values-ar
>
> values-ku

and I put my own language in default values, but when I install my app from Google Play it returns to `values-en` automatically

My values folder

[image]

Comment: The language chosen depends on the language you set in your phone setting. Your phone setting now is english right?

Comment: yes, but i want to set default language to the one i want not

Comment: You could make a Shared Preference to change the language on the fly AND save it for the next runs. So, the next time the app is launched, it reads the setting and starts your app in the saved language. You could save the language as `ar`, `en` or `ku`, for simplicity.

Comment: could you give me more detail about this please? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force using your language by (call it  in each activity's onCreate) :

```
public static void forceLocale(Context ctx, Locale locale) {
        Configuration conf = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = locale;
        ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        Configuration systemConf = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration();
        systemConf.locale = locale;
        Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(systemConf, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());

        Locale.setDefault(locale);
    }
```